# How to install .Net 6 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, .net-framework

I'm writing .Net code that needs a priority queue and would like to use this one: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-6.0

Which says it needs .Net 6. Do I have that already installed?

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP" /s
```

... many screenfuls of output that seem to be talking about versions 2 and 3, but the highest versions mentioned, seem to be

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\1033
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033
    CBS    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Release    REG_DWORD    0x80ff4
    Servicing    REG_DWORD    0x0
    TargetVersion    REG_SZ    4.0.0
    Version    REG_SZ    4.8.04084

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0
    (Default)    REG_SZ    deprecated

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0\Client
    Install    REG_DWORD    0x1
    Version    REG_SZ    4.0.0.0
```

... 4.x. And sure enough, when I try to compile code using PriorityQueue, the compiler will have none of it. Okay, Google leads me to what looks like an installer for .Net 6 Desktop Runtime: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-6.0.2-windows-x64-installer

Download, run, click through the various prompts, it claims successful completion.

And... Nothing has changed. Compiler gives the same error messages, and the attempt to check what versions are installed, gives exactly the same output as before.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to install .Net 6 on Windows 10?

You already did.

> What am I missing?

The framework died at 4.8. What you want is now called .NET. .NET Core has jumped versions – going from 3.x to 5.x and then 6 and is now known as .NET

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Type `cmd`

On the command prompt, type `dotnet --version`

(if you've installed the SDK)

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions`

(if you love regedit)

https://www.iowacomputergurus.com/insights/article/microsoft-announces-end-of-net-framework-net-core-meet-net-5

Comment: .NET Framework didn't "die" at 4.8, Microsoft just decided to open the source code for .NET Framework, the resulting project is .NET Core. When Windows 10 was announced they indicate that .NET Core would then replace the .NET Framework (it was originally two projects).  They skipped .NET Core 4.x for obvious reasons. Just installing .NET Core isn't enough he author has to change which version they are targeting within Visual Studio

Comment: It’s not called .Net Core anymore either.  Version 6 is just .NET.